# Can we clarify the off-topic closing options?

Tags: feature-request, closing-questions, migration

[Evidently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196104/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-migration?noredirect=1#comment618909_196104), when we vote to close a question as off-topic and appropriate for Stack Overflow, the thread will not actually be migrated unless we select:

```
close
 -> off-topic because…
     -> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
         -> belongs on stackoverflow.com
```

Put differently, if we select:

```
close
 -> Questions about programming are off-topic here unless they involve statistical 
    analysis in some fashion, but they can be asked on Stack Overflow.
```

the question will simply go [on hold] for a period of time, and eventually be closed automatically.  I did not realize this, and I gather [it was an issue on programmers.SE as well](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/confusing-closing-off-topic-dialog).  Thus, I wonder if others were also using the latter option because it is more salient, rather than because they wanted to close the question ***without*** it being migrated.

I'm wondering if we can edit the options that appear when you vote to close to make this clearer.  I don't have a specific suggestion on how to do that; I'm open to ideas that people have and I'm not even sure what options are possible.  I don't want to prevent people from being able to close without migrating if that's their intention, but I don't want posters to end up in limbo due to confusing design.

---

*Side question*:  Can [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69065/frequency-table-comparison-using-r) be migrated?

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for raising it and thereby leading to things working in a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, this was really confusing -- I have removed "Questions about programming..." close reason.

Comment: I think that will resolve the issue, thanks. (& thanks for migrating)